# Homology of Hirzebruch surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $\mathbb{F}_n:=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(-n)\oplus\mathcal{O}(0))$ be the $n$th Hirzebruch surface, where $\mathcal{O}(k)$ is the canonical line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb C$, for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. I'm trying to compute the homology groups of the surfaces $\mathbb F_n$. The unique reference I've found is [this](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Hirzebruch_surfaces), but, in truth, it is unclear to me how to proceed. Can someone help me?

Comment: The Betti numbers are 1, 0, 2, 0, 1 for all n, and there is no torsion. Probably the reference you have contains this. Are you asking you do you actually check this?

Comment: Substantially yes. In the reference I linked the author, in order  to compute the homology groups, decomposes the surfaces $\mathbb F_n$ in a way that I really don't understand.

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro The Hirzebruch surfaces are $S^2$ bundles over $S^2$, and the spectral sequence for a fiber bundle will immediately give you the above homology groups.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic Can you suggest to me a reference where I can study these spectral sequences for fiber bundles?

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro A quick, practical introduction is given in Griffiths-Morgan “Rational Homotopy Theory and Differential Forms”; a much more in-depth reference is McCleary’s “A User’s Guide to Spectral Sequences”.

Comment: You could also use Hurewicz to say $H_1 = 0$ and $H_2 = \mathbb{Z}^2$. The rest follows from this. (Here I'm using the fact that the $S^2$ bundle has a section.)

Comment: You could also use the well-known fact that the Hirzebruch surfaces with $n$ even are diffeomorphic to $S^2 \times S^2$ and the ones with $n$ odd are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^2 \#\bar{\mathbb{C}}P^2$ (the blowup of $\mathbb{C}P^2$). This tells you the intersection form as well as the homology groups.

Comment: @DannyRuberman I'm computing the homology just to give a proof of this fact :)

Comment: @VincenzoZaccaro Computing the homology won't give you this fact. Just knowing the homotopy type of a 4-manifold doesn't tell you what it is up to diffeomorphism.

Comment: @DannyRuberman take a look at the reference I linked.

Answer (score 4):

Various approach are suggested in the comments. Let me give some hints for an easy method. The nice thing about Hirzebruch, or rational ruled, surfaces is they are trivial over $V= \mathbb{P}^1-\{\infty\}$. So that the preimage $U$ is the product $\mathbb{P}^1\times V$. 
Let $Z=\mathbb{F}_n-U$. This is just a projective line. Now use the sequence
$$\ldots H_c^i(U)\to H^i(\mathbb{F}_n)\to H^i(Z)\to H^{i+1}_c(U)\ldots$$
where the group on the left is compactly supported cohomology. Now you should have enough information to hopefully finish the computation, which would give $H^2(\mathbb{F_n})=\mathbb{Z}^2$ for example.

Comment: Tahnks for the idea :)